# Executar método apenas se existir propriedade específica no objeto. Sem fazer testes a cada linha com hasOwnProperty() ou comparando com undefined

Tags: javascript, testes-automatizados

Estou trabalhando com testes automatizados e no meu caso tenho vários objetos que contém as configurações que vão ser inseridas nos campos do sistema.

Ai tenho os métodos **Set** que preenchem os campos com as configurações no objeto dados, por exemplo:

```
dados = {
    nome: "Diego",
    sobrenome: "Henrique",
    idade: "22"
}

preencheCliente(dados){
    fillNome(dados.nome);
    fillSobrenome(dados.sobrenome);
    fillIdade(dados.idade);
}
```

Gostaria de ter objetos sem alguma propriedade e que continuasse a funcionar com o método `preencheCliente()`, entretanto vai acusar um >>>erro<<< ao fazer Set da Idade, exemplo:

```
dados2 = {
    nome: "Diego",
    sobrenome: "Henrique"
}

preencheCliente(dados){
    fillNome(dados.nome);
    fillSobrenome(dados.sobrenome);
    >>>fillIdade(dados.idade);<<<
}
```

Coloquei no título **Não resolve com hasOwnProperty()**, por conta que, imagine agora que tenho já implementado mais de 100 campos, teria que ajustar para cada método preenche (`preencheCliente`, `preencheProduto`, `preencheEndereco`, etc) e para cada campo fazer o teste

**if (dados.hasOwnProperty("NOME_PROPRIEDADE_OBJ"))**:

```
preencheCliente(dados){
    if (dados.hasOwnProperty('nome'))
      fillNome(dados.nome);
    if (dados.hasOwnProperty('sobrenome'))
      fillSobrenome(dados.sobrenome);
    if (dados.hasOwnProperty('idade'))
      fillIdade(dados.idade);
}
```

Além do `hasOwnProperty()` existem outros 2 meios que descobri:

Operador **IN** e **comparando com undefined**. Ver mais em:
https://dmitripavlutin.com/check-if-object-has-property-javascript/

Entretanto sempre cai na edição massiva de colar um teste antes das linhas..

Existe solução pra isso, sem implementar todos esses condicionais? Ou teria que fazer algum outro tipo de abordagem?

Comment: De onde vem este `Sys.Field...`? Você também pode usar `Object.entries` para iterar sobre as chaves de um objeto, mas fica difícil dar uma resposta detalhada sem saber o que é este `Sys`

Comment: Inventei para o exemplo, é do framework do TestComplete. Sys.FieldNome seria um COMObject, onde consigo acessar propriedades e métodos de uma janela do sistema por exemplo. Irei modificar o exemplo

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução seria iterar através das chaves deste objeto se você deseja executar alguma verifica em cada chave, exemplo:

```js
const dados = {
    nome: "Diego",
    sobrenome: "Henrique",
    idade: "22"
}

const keys = Object.keys(dados); // [nome, sobrenome, idade]

for (const key in keys){
  // Faça algo com a chave 
}
```

Desta maneira se uma chave não existe no objeto a mesma não será passada para o array keys. Você pode acessar o valor fazendo `dados[key]`, esta seria uma solução escalável se você precisa executar a mesma operação para 1 ou N chaves dentro ao objeto sem ter que diretamente controlar chave por chave.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de mudar as chamada sugiro mudar a abordagem e fazer a alteração na definição dos métodos `preenche...` para verificar se um valor foi passado:

```js
preencheIdade(idade) {
  if (!idade) { // ou idade === undefined
    return;
  }
  // sua lógica continua aqui
}
```